# Communication between remote Angular app and Electron desktop app

Tags: angular, electron, ipc, communication

the scenario is the following:

- An Angular app deployed in an external server
- Desktop electron app running locally serving a remote url (the one where the Angular is served from)

Is there any way to use electron API to interact with the OS from the Angular app? I do believe IPC will not work since they are not running on the same instance, but I wanted to know if someone can come up with another solution.

Thanks, Javi

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research it seems feasible to use IPC to and from an Angular app.

Since the Angular app is rendered in a `Renderer Process`, it's possible to call `ipcRenderer` module in order to have such communication:

In `Main Process` in Electron app:

```js
const { ipcMain } = require('electron');

ipcMain.on('customChannel', (event, args) => {
  console.log('event: ', event);
  console.log('args: ', args);
});
```

On Angular app, on a component:

```js
// Component implementing OnInit

ngOnInit(): void {
 if ((<any>window).require) {
   try {
    const ipc = (<any>window).require('electron').ipcRenderer;
    ipc.send('customChannel', 'this is a test');
   } catch (error) {
    throw error;
   }
  } else {
     console.warn('Could not load electron ipc');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in above example the remote web application has electron installed. In case some one wants to communicate without having the electron dependency on the web app then we can use contextBridge.

In your electron app

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
  'electron',   //This will be exposed as window.electron in your remote app
  {
    doThing: () => ipcRenderer.send('do-a-thing')
  }
)
```

In your remote app

```
window.electron.doThing()
```

Source https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/context-bridge